# How (i.e., what intent action) to start the set up email account activity (add new email account activity) of the email application

Tags: android, android-intent, action

From within my app, I'd like to start the set up new email account activity of the Email App which looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNYnj.png

I've looked at this http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Email/AndroidManifest.xml

and tried to start the set up email activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.email.CREATE_ACCOUNT");
startActivity(intent);
```

But I got an exception:
    E/AndroidRuntime(517): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.email.CREATE_ACCOUNT }

Anyone please help me?

Thanks so much,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for from APIs 4.0+.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.email.CREATE_ACCOUNT");
intent.putExtra("FLOW_MODE", 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

Below works for from APIs 2.1+. Maybe also work for lower versions (not tested).

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics");
intent.putExtra("FLOW_MODE", 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You can pre-fill the email address ("user name") and the password using the extras EXTRA_USERNAME, EXTRA_PASSWORD. See http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Email/src/com/android/email/activity/setup/AccountSetupBasics.java#102

Answer (score 0):

you could try using an explicit intent. instead of

```
new Intent("com.android.email.CREATE_ACCOUNT")
```

use

```
new Intent(context, com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics.class)
```

you may also want to look into the whole [ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT) action string. it may do what you are looking for without having to use a SPECIFIC app. for example, when an oem installs a different email app from the stock android one. if it happens  there won't be anything to handle either the explicity or implicit intent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, `new Intent(context, com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics)` --> error: "com.android.email cannot be resolved to a variable". The ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT action string is to add an account for the device. My issue is to add an EMAIL account (not device account).

Comment: oops. it should have a .class at the end. updated the answer to fix that

Comment: even with a .class at the end --> got the same error. Look like there is no such accessible package and class. I am using API level 14 (4.0).

Comment: it's sounding like the activity isn't on your device. have you tried on multiple devices?

Comment: I have my own solution. Thanks.