# Is there a way to create an imap email account from another application on android

Tags: android, email

I am trying to ease the process of syncing contacts, calendars and mail on an android device with a specific service provider. My intention is to provide an application that is based on davdroid to sync the calendar and contacts after the user has provided username and password.

Now I'd like to setup an email account on the device at the same time, using the same user credentials that is entered in the sync app. Is there a way to do that without having to rewrite the default email application?

I have found some indications on how to open the account settings, but not how to provide the correct imap server details. ([How (i.e., what intent action) to start the set up email account activity (add new email account activity) of the email application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765048/how-i-e-what-intent-action-to-start-the-set-up-email-account-activity-add-n))

Related question on this issue, without answers though: [Is there a way to setup an e-mail account through a third party android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247165/is-there-a-way-to-setup-an-e-mail-account-through-a-third-party-android-app).

Answer (score -1):

javamail can provide you for access imap and pop3 account so that you can edit account or sync
this is [javamail  for Android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=additionnal.jar&can=2&q=)

Comment: Hi henry4343, thanks for your answer!
Just to set my expectations right;
 - Will I be able to add/edit settings for the default mail client using javamail? 
 - or do I have to run my own sync service, fetching mails that can be browsed in the default mail application
 - or is this to create a completely new mail application?